# Dynamic custom Attribute not showing

Tags: jquery, dom, element

I have the following code that is part of a dynamic loop and creates a new grid with 1 column and 4 rows.  The forth row has a  button:

```
var elem = $(this,'a[data-itemid]');
$(elem).prop('data-itemid', '"'+value+'"');
console.log($(elem).prop('data-itemid'));
console.log(elem);
```

Using developer console, here is how the  is drawn:

```
<a data-role="button" name="orderButton" dsid="orderButton" class="menuMaster_orderButton    ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-none ui-btn-icon-nowhere ui-shadow ui-corner-all" id="menuMaster_orderButton" data-corners="true" data-icon="none" data-iconpos="nowhere" data-mini="false" data-theme="b" tabindex="7" role="button">Order!</a>
```

As it cycles through each record, I have the above code which should add a new attribute called 'data-itemid' and a value.  On this line:

```
console.log($(elem).prop('data-itemid'));
```

It gives me the correct value.  So I know it's adding the new attribute.  But I do not think its adding it to   because i cannot find it at all.

```
console.log(elem);
```

This gives me :

```
[Window, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", size: function…]
```

Which is not the element :(

**UPDATE**:

This what i am using during the loop as the buttons being created:

```
$(this,'a[name=orderButton]').data('itemid', value);
```

This is what is used to fetch it onClick:

```
console.log('itemid= '+$(this, 'a[name=orderButton]').data('itemid'));
```

The above comes back undefined.

Comment: `console.log(elem);` prints the said value because it is a jQuery object... you can try `console.log(elem[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery stores all `data` attributes in an object in memory to improve performance. Any attributes added to an element after the DOM has loaded is stored in this object only, and will not visible in the HTML source.

You can verify a `data` attribute has been set by using `data()` to retrieve it. Do not use `prop('data-x')` or `attr('data-x');` as it the attributes are not guaranteed to exist for the above reason, and it's much slower.

With this in mind your first example should be:

```
var elem = $(this,'a[data-itemid]');
$(elem).data('itemid', value);
console.log($(elem).data('itemid'));
console.log(elem);
```

Comment: I get the same issue, in that it shows in the console, but not in the element to retrieve it.

Comment: It's not an issue - that's how it works. To set use `$el.data('foo', 'bar');` to get use `x = $el.data('foo');`

Comment: OKay, but  its not showing in the rendered <a> element, but it is showing in console `console.log($(this, 'a[data-itemid).data('itemid'));`   And when i click on the button (<a>) I get undefined when i try to retrieve it.

Comment: This is what i am using to retrieve the value from itemid: `console.log('itemid= '+$(this, 'a[name=orderButton]').data('itemid'));`  Based onClick event() being fired  This is what i use to load it during the loop `$(this,'a[name=orderButton]').data('itemid', value);`  Which again is correct syntax ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a context selector when you have a reference to `this` in the handler. Try: `$(this).data('itemid', value);`

Comment: Its because, I am not sure what (this) actually is, and i wanted to make sure it hit the <a> element.

Comment: If it's inside a click handler, `this `will be the element matched by the selector.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you Rory :)